# Ticks attribute not working in chartist.js

Tags: javascript, charts

Here's some simple code with two charts: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4sqzseo/3/)
The ticks attribute works fine with the line chart but does not with the bar chart. Interestingly it works fine when posted on Chartist website (in examples section). But I really need to have it working in my .js file.

```
new Chartist.Bar(
    '#barChart', 
    {
        labels: ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5'],
        series: [
            {name: 'one', data: [5, 6, 8, 9, 5]},
            {name: 'two', data: [4, 5, 6, 5, 4]},
            {name: 'three', data: [2, 4, 5, 2, 1]}
        ]
    },
    {
        width: 565,
        height: 200,
        axisY: {
            type: Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,  
            low: 0,
            high: 10,
            ticks: [0, 5, 10]                // the ticks don't show up 
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the diference between your code and examples code in [chartist web](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html). And they are loading `scripts/all.js` js url as :

```
<script async="" src="scripts/all.js"></script>
```

So, add that code and it will work :

```
<script src="//gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/scripts/all.js"></script>
```

It seems to be a different module (`AUTO-SCALE-AXIS.JS`) from the main.js

https://jsfiddle.net/g4sqzseo/4/

That is the function from [github project](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/blob/master/dist/chartist.js)  reference chartist.js which is not working for you :

````
/**
 * The fixed scale axis uses standard linear projection of values along an axis. It makes use of a divisor option to divide the range provided from the minimum and maximum value or the options high and low that will override the computed minimum and maximum.
 * **Options**
 * The following options are used by this axis in addition to the default axis options outlined in the axis configuration of the chart default settings.
 * ```javascript
 * var options = {
 *   // If high is specified then the axis will display values explicitly up to this value and the computed maximum from the data is ignored
 *   high: 100,
 *   // If low is specified then the axis will display values explicitly down to this value and the computed minimum from the data is ignored
 *   low: 0,
 *   // If specified then the value range determined from minimum to maximum (or low and high) will be divided by this number and ticks will be generated at those division points. The default divisor is 1.
 *   divisor: 4,
 *   // If ticks is explicitly set, then the axis will not compute the ticks with the divisor, but directly use the data in ticks to determine at what points on the axis a tick need to be generated.
 *   ticks: [1, 10, 20, 30]
 * };
 * ```
 *
 * @module Chartist.FixedScaleAxis
 */
/* global Chartist */
(function (window, document, Chartist) {
  'use strict';

  function FixedScaleAxis(axisUnit, data, chartRect, options) {
    var highLow = Chartist.getHighLow(data.normalized, options, axisUnit.pos);
    this.divisor = options.divisor || 1;
    this.ticks = options.ticks || Chartist.times(this.divisor).map(function(value, index) {
      return highLow.low + (highLow.high - highLow.low) / this.divisor * index;
    }.bind(this));
    this.range = {
      min: highLow.low,
      max: highLow.high
    };

    Chartist.FixedScaleAxis.super.constructor.call(this,
      axisUnit,
      chartRect,
      this.ticks,
      options);

    this.stepLength = this.axisLength / this.divisor;
  }

  function projectValue(value) {
    return this.axisLength * (+Chartist.getMultiValue(value, this.units.pos) - this.range.min) / (this.range.max - this.range.min);
  }

  Chartist.FixedScaleAxis = Chartist.Axis.extend({
    constructor: FixedScaleAxis,
    projectValue: projectValue
  });

}(window, document, Chartist));
````